# user profile synchronization service running account cannot change

Tags: ups

I have just setup a new SP2013 farm. I run the installation using DOMAIN\administrator. After complete the configuration wizard, I start the central admin and launch the farm configration wizard. In the wizard first step I type in DOMAIN\farmadmin as the future farm admin. After it run for a long time, I refresh the page and get some error. Hence I re-run the product configuration wizard -> run farm configuration wizard again. It seems working this time.

However, when I try to start the "User Profile Synchronization Service" under "Services on Server", the "Account Name" field is greyed out. It is DOMAIN\administrator and not allowing me change it to farmadmin.

What can I do?

Comment: If you change the farm admin account, then you need to recreate the USer Profile services. delete it and recreate it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The user Profile Sync service must be run in the context of the farm account.  That is still one of the requirements.

during provisioning, the code for the UPSS validates that the account that it is set to run as is the same as the account that the OWSTIMER (SPTimerV4) is running under.

You CANNOT change the account running the FIM Services.  It MUST be the Farm Admin (same user running owstimer.exe).  There is an explicit check for this account during UPSS provisioning.  If the account running owstimer.exe isn't the same account running the FIM services, UPSS will not start.

In your case, i think delete current User profile service and re create it will get the new farm admin account.

Answer (score 0):

Restart the SharePoint Timer Service

[image]

Then check the User Profile Service. It should be in Started state

Comment: But I want to change the running account of User Profile Sync service before start it.

Comment: check this URL : http://jaxsharepoint.blogspot.com/2013/08/setup-and-start-sharepoint-2013-user.html